# Send POST parameters in header()?

Tags: php, forms, session, authentication, header

I'm making a register page, signup.php, and basically what I want it to do is check for errors and if there are none, redirect to register.php. That is fine and whatnot, but register.php is the page where the actual account is made (e.g. mySQL query). Of course, in order to do that, I actually need the params gathered form signup.php. I was wondering if I could do something like this..

```
    header("Location: register.php, TYPE: POST, PARAMS: {user,pass,email}")
```

Obviously I can not use $_GET as I am transmitting sensitive data (e.g. passwords).

Any ideas/suggestions?

EDIT: Thank you all for your answers. I am now storing the parameters in a $_SESSION variable.

Comment: And you believe that a header will be any more secure?

Comment: +1. Users can read headers if they want, so sending data in POST headers, if in plaintext, is just as insecure as GET headers.

Comment: I'm afraid you guys did not understand. I just do not want the password to appear in the URL. It will be sent in MD5'ed form. The reason I use a redirect is that I want the user to click a link in a email and _then_ create the account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't, and such data would be just as insecure to any determined attacker.

Store the data in a session variable for use in the next page.

Answer (score 2):

I see no point in such redirect.

Why not to post right away to register.php?
And then check for errors and save data in database in the same register.php?
without any redirects

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is possible, you will hit another brick wall - the implementation of redirects in the popular browsers. While the standard requires, that it asks the user if a post is redirected, all popular browsers simply interpret the redirect as a GET. In short: you can't redirect a POST that way, you'll have to find another way without a round trip to the client, or use GET.

Also, you should be aware that unless your requests are done via https, both GET and POST will present the sensitive information to any listener, as POST simply buts the query string into the http request and not the url. Security wise, both are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could store them in the $_SESSION and refer to those in the register.php page, doing some checking to make sure someone has actually filled out the information and didn't just navigate to it.